# What are models in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I don't really understand what a model is in AngularJS. I know what a model is in the context of an MVC framework. For example in PHP I would create a model, like ApiModel.php or something like that, and in there I would put all sorts of cool stuff for the controller to work with.

This doesn't seem to be the way AngularJS thinks of models, in fact I can't find any good explanation of how to implement a model in AngularJS, but everywhere talks about them.

What is a model in AngularJS and how do I use them in the traditional MVC way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model in AngularJS specifically communicates with its associated views and controllers and notifies it whether there is a change in its state.

A more thorough description of what is a model can be found in the following link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140502052028/http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/04/24/modeling-data-and-state-in-your-angularjs-application/) is relevant to your inquiry.

More specifically, he mentions that

> Model classes encapsulate your application’s data and provide an API to access and manipulate that data. The other classes in your application will make requests of models via this API. When data on the model is updated, the model dispatches events that the other classes within your application can react to. Models are appropriate for capturing the domain logic, such as performing calculations or other manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

A model is just the data that your application consumes.

If the data needs to be dynamic (i.e subject to CRUD operations) you would get this data from a remote source like a database (or even a flat-file) using angularjs' $http in a service or factory and then pass it to the Controller.

If you have a small app for read-only data, then you can hard-code it directly into a Controller.

The most popular data format for angularjs applications these days is JSON because of its flexibility.

The view (or front-end) would then access this data that lives on the scope in the Controller using ng-bind or ng-model or interpolation {{...}}